# Release H2O Grid From Memory?

Tags: r, h2o

I am struggling to find the correct API for releasing memory for an object created by the H2O grid. This code was pre-written by someone else and I am currently maintaining it.

```
#train grid search
gbm_grid1 <- h2o.grid(algorithm = "gbm"                                  #specifies gbm algorithm is used
                      ,grid_id = paste("gbm_grid1",current_date,sep="_")   #defines a grid identification
                      ,x = predictors                                    #defines column variables to use as predictors
                      ,y = y                                             #specifies the response variable
                      ,training_frame = train1                           #specifies the training frame
                      
                      #gbm parameters to remain fixed
                      ,nfolds = 5                     #specify number of folds for cross-validation is 5 (this acceptable here in order to reduce training time)
                      ,distribution = "bernoulli"     #specify that we are predicting a binary dependent variable
                      ,ntrees = 1000                  #specify the number of trees to build (1000 as essentially the maximum number of trees that can be built. Early stopping parameters defined later will make it unlikely our model will reach 1000 trees)
                      ,learn_rate = 0.1               #specify the learn rate used of for gradient descent optimization (goal is to use as small a learn rate as possible)
                      ,learn_rate_annealing = 0.995   #specifies that the learn rate will perpetually decrease by a factor of 0.995 (this can help speed up traing for our grid search)
                      ,max_depth = tuned_max_depth
                      ,min_rows = tuned_min_rows
                      ,sample_rate = 0.8              #specify the amount of row observations used when making a split decision
                      ,col_sample_rate = 0.8          #specify the amount of column observations used when making a split decision
                      ,stopping_metric = "logloss"    #specify loss function
                      ,stopping_tolerance = 0.001     #specify minimum change required in stopping metric for individual model to continue training
                      ,stopping_rounds = 5            #specify maximum amount of training rounds stopping metric has to change in excess of stopping tolerance
                      
                      #specifies hyperparameters to fluctuate during model building in the grid search
                      ,hyper_params = gbm_hp2
                      
                      #specifies the search criteria that includes stop training etrics to speed up model building
                      ,search_criteria = search_criteria2
                      
                      #sets a reproducible seed
                      ,seed = 123456                         
)

h2o.rm(gbm_grid1)
```

The problem is I believe this code was written awhile ago and has been deprecated since. `h2o.rm(gbm_grid1)` fails and R Studio tells me that I require a hex identifier. So I assigned my object an identifier and tried `h2o.rm(gbm_grid1, "identifier.hex")` and it tells me I cannot release this type of object.

The issue is I run out of memory if I move onto the next steps of the script. What should I do?

This is what I get with H2O.ls()

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can remove objects with `h2o.rm()`. You can use the variable name or key.

```
h2o.rm(your_object)
h2o.rm(‘your_key’)
```

You can use `h2o.ls()` to check what objects are in memory. Also, you can add the argument `cascade = TRUE` to the `rm` method to remove sub-models.

See more [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/h2o/man/h2o.rm.html)

Comment: The problem though is I can't seem to release gbm_grid2. When I do, it tells me it failed. And it needs to be an h2o object. Is it not an h2o object? It seems this code worked in the past, but recent API changes have deprecated it.

Comment: Try `h2o.rm('gbm_grid2')`. I just tested it on 3.32.0.1, and it works

Comment: Cool, the command ran through just fine. But my memory has not seemed to recover. Based on the script I gave above where gbm_grid2 is my local variable ... am I recovering memory correctly that way? I've also updated my post with the results of h2o.ls()

Comment: You are correctly recovering memory, but you need to do it for each grid you create. Your screenshot shows objects from gbm_grid1, try also doing `h2o.rm('gbm_grid1')`. Whatever you see returned in `h2o.ls()`, you can call to remove. You can also remove all objects using `h2o.removeAll()`.

Comment: Okay cool I'm iterating over with h2o.ls(). Is there a way to determine which h2o object is taking the most memory? I don't see that information in h2o.ls() The reason why is even after iterating through and removing almost every object my memory is still at 95%.

Comment: In H2O Flow, you can use List All Frames to see how much memory they are using but not for models